# Need to understand Xcode's cryptic crash report

Tags: xcode, uipasteboard

So I need to understand the contents of this picture.

[image: Text]

I have searched through the other articles related to this on StackOverflow and I haven't found an answer or even another URL to a reference explaining this.

A little bit of context:

I am using UIPasteboard.general to copy some text and whenever I send the app to the background and enter any other application the former app crashes.

Now what's confusing is that I can still successfully paste what UIPasteboard has copied but still the app has crashed.

So I would like to troubleshoot but I do not have the slightest idea of where to begin looking at this.

So **any** insight anyone can give in this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sharing some resources I found in my search

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/414
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/412

Comment: Did you at least set the Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: I did but cannot create the same error, even though I haven't changed anything. Working with UIPasteboard is a bit flaky.